# Not Able to query 'FlowDefinitionView' object in post install script

Tags: apex, managed-package, isv

We are tried to query the salesforce 'FlowDefinitionView' object in the post install script, got the following error.

```
Element isTemplate is duplicated at this location in type Flow.
```

Following code we tried.

```
SELECT Id, ActiveVersionId, ApiName, IsActive, Label, NamespacePrefixFROM FlowDefinitionView.
```

My PostInstallScript class has global access and without sharing permission. Is anything we missed? Any thought on this?

Comment: This looks more like an error deploying metadata. E.g. as described here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000317976&type=1
Is that query the only thing you're doing in the post install script? If not, how are you sure that the error is due to querying the FlowDefinitionView?

Comment: @GuyClairbois, Thanks, we have more codes in the post install script with in the try catch. The exception throws from this query line.

Comment: I don't think there's a reason why a query would throw this exception. You might need to contact Salesforce support if you're sure it's that line.